OpenAPI - deepObject in query parameters is not recognized
I'm trying to develop a Micronaut Java server with OpenAPI spec according to this guide. Overall project logic is pretty much the same, but a little more complicated.
Quick data structure description: There is a "polling station" entity with its own number and address with region code it's located in (station number is unique within region).
What I'm trying to achieve: 'GET' endpoint from which I can query stations by one or more region codes OR by one or more station numbers (one filter type at a time, so scenario when both station number and region code are provided shouldn't be possible).
I decided to use filter object and provide it through query parameters, like Helen suggested here or Debargha Roy here.
Also I checked the correctness of deepObject usage in https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query. The deepObject property description:

deepObject – simple non-nested objects are serialized as paramName[prop1]=value1&paramName[prop2]=value2&.... The behavior for nested objects and arrays is undefined.

So the usage in the url below should be correct (-g flag is for curl to not recognize the []).
Here is the realization I have now:
OpenAPI version: 3.0.3
Endpoint (page and limit params are not relevant):
  /v1/stations/filtered:
    get:
      tags:
        - brief_station_info
      summary: Search for all polling stations, divided by page with limit, and filter by region code(s) or station number(s).
      operationId: getStationsFiltered
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/stationsFilterQueryParam"
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/pageNumberQueryParam"
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/limitNumberQueryParam"
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/StationList"
        400:
          description: Bad Request

Query param:
    stationsFilterQueryParam:
      name: filter
      in: query
      description: Filter object to filter stations by one or more region codes or station numbers.
      required: true
      style: deepObject
      explode: true
      allowReserved: true
      schema:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/StationsFilter"

Filter object itself:
    StationsFilter:
      title: Stations Filter
      description: Provides stations filter object to 
        filter by region code(s) or ps_number(s).
      type: object
      properties:
        region-code:
          type: string
          example: 'MOW,CE'
        ps-number:
          type: string
          example: '918,920'
      minProperties: 1
      maxProperties: 1
      additionalProperties: false

The problem is irrelevant to min/maxProperties and "only one filter option" restriction as a whole (doesn't work anyway, with or without it).
The curl command used for testing (swagger generates the same one, only without -g flag):
curl -X 'GET' -g 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stations/filtered?filter[region-code]=MOW,CE&page=1&limit=10' -H 'accept: application/json'

All I'm getting is 400 and the following result from curl (ofc the desired result is 200):
{"_links":{"self":[{"href":"/api/v1/stations/filtered?filter[region-code]=MOW,CE&page=1&limit=10","templated":false}]},"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Required QueryValue [filter] not specified","path":"/filter"}]},"message":"Bad Request"}

Request doesn't reach the controller, so there is little sense in providing it's code.
Here is generated StationsFilter class code, just in case:
/**
 * Provides stations filter object to filter by region code(s) or ps_number(s)
 */
@Schema(name = "StationsFilter", description = "Provides stations filter object to filter by region code(s) or ps_number(s)")
@Serdeable
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    StationsFilter.JSON_PROPERTY_REGION_CODE,
    StationsFilter.JSON_PROPERTY_PS_NUMBER
})
@Generated("io.micronaut.openapi.generator.JavaMicronautServerCodegen")
public class StationsFilter {

    public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_REGION_CODE = "region-code";
    public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_PS_NUMBER = "ps-number";

    @Nullable(inherited = true)
    @Schema(name = "region-code", example = "MOW,CE", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.NOT_REQUIRED)
    @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_REGION_CODE)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    private String regionCode;

    @Nullable(inherited = true)
    @Schema(name = "ps-number", example = "918,920", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.NOT_REQUIRED)
    @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_PS_NUMBER)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    private String psNumber;

    ...

I've already spent 3 hours trying to understand what I made wrong, so any help is very appreciated)
P.S. my operating system is Debian 12, if it's somehow relevant.
